# Set User-Agent in HTTP request

Tags: angularjs, http, user-agent

Is it possible to set the user-agent in an HTTP request?
I tried the following:

```
$http({
        method: 'GET',
        url: 'http://rest-service.guides.spring.io/greeting',
        headers: {
            'User-Agent' : 'app/2.0 (Android 4.3) sec=some_key'
        }

     })
```

But my browser says:

> Refused to set unsafe header "User-Agent"

Comment: I don't think you can do this. You are making an ajax request through the browser which will enforce its own security policies on it.

Comment: is there a way to solve this?

Comment: In other words, it depends on the browser, but in general, no. @1101 why do you want to do this?

Answer (score 0):

There is a way in backend specific solution.

Call your own rest service with default header parameters and then in your rest service call another rest service which is you want to call , with custom User-Agent header( Restception :) ). Then you can get your data from your own rest service.

hon2a points the link,  that has similar problem. [XMLHttpRequest Termination](http://www.w3.org/TR/XMLHttpRequest/#terminate-the-request)